# Open and close a set of workbooks one by one by an HTML/JS add-in

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I am wondering if it is possible to let an HTML/JS add-in open and close a set of workbooks one by one.

I have not seen the JavaScript API to open or close a workbook, and don't know if it is doable in a JavaScript function.

Otherwise, because VBA can repeat opening and closing workbooks, is it possible to set a mechanism in VBA to run systematically a function of an HTML/JS add-in every time a workbook is open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality for this in the JS APIs.  We are aware of the gap, and it is on the long-term roadmap, but not something on the immediate horizon.

Depending on whether the workbook being opened already has your Office Add-in inserted or not, though, you can probably do a VBA workaround.  Namely, you could have the Office Add-in create a binding (if it's not already there) on some well-known cell in a hidden sheet, and attach an event listener to it. VBA would then go and write in to the same cell, triggering the event. Again, this only works if the add-in is already inserted and essentially in a template-like scenario; but if it fits your requirements, then that would work.

Best!

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT

Comment: So now the question is, whether it is possible to insert by default an add-in into a set of workbooks? I don't need a general solution, I just want to make this work on my own machine and on a (large) set of my own workbooks...

Comment: On existing workbooks? You should be able to do this with open xml, though you'll have to dig around to figure out how to do this (you can also crack open the Excel file and see what is inserted for the add-in, to serve as inspiration).  For new workbooks, you would just create them off of the template that already has the add-in inserted.

Comment: On existing workbooks... So in which languages and by which tools could we modify the open xml of a set of workbooks?

Comment: You would use the OpenXML SDK, using C# or VB.NET (as a console/WinForms app).  However, you'll need to trailblaze a bit.  Links such as https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa982683(v=office.12).aspx, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456489(v=office.12).aspx, or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb508029(v=office.12).aspx may be helpful...

Comment: Cool, i could dig a little bit, thank you... To systematically run a function of an (automatically loaded) add-in of a (VBA-opened) workbook, you think the event handling is the best workaround? We could well set a mechanism in `app.initialize = function () {...`: wait several seconds until the workbook is well opened and stabilised, then call the function, no?

Comment: For the OOXML part, I reached out to a couple people who may have a code sample, I'll let you know if they get back to me.  For event handling vs. Office.initialize, it's up to you.  If there's ever only one function than you want to call, yeah, that would work, though at that point you don't really need VBA.  If it's something that only needs to be triggered conditionally, that's where the event would be the way to go.

Comment: Looking forward to code sample of OOXML... For the other part, I think I still need VBA to open and close a large number of workbooks one by one. So, in `app.initialize`, how could I make sure my function is called after the workbook is well opened and stabilised (also automatic VBA events while opening a workbook is possible)?

Comment: The task pane itself will only open in the document once the document is open and stabilized.  Not sure about ordering of VBA events, though.  That's where having a binding bound to a cell into which VBA writes could serve as a trigger.

Comment: That's a good news... Actually, Michael, the reason why I want to repeat running an add-in (rather than a VBA code) on a large number of workbooks is to measure and record their calculation time. If I do the measurement by a VBA code, my desktop will become busier and busier, a calculation will be slower than normal. My assumption is that measuring by a JS command will run the calculation on the server? So it will be relatively more correct? Do you think my assumption holds?

Comment: I think this becomes an entirely different question... but in truth, I don't see why the JS would be any more accurate than VBA.  The "server" that it's calculating on, on the Desktop, is just the desktop.  So if that's all you're using it for, I think that VBA will actually be far and away easier, and probably no less accurate.

Comment: I still don't understand where is the "server". If I put all the HTML/JS files in my remote server holding my website and let `manifest.xml` point to them, their execution over a local workbook will be on the server holding my website or on my Desktop?

Comment: On the desktop.  Both the JS execution and the API calls into Excel will run on your machine, and the API calls will run directly on an Excel thread just like VBA.  The only time when the server is remote is Excel Online